# JSON DateTime serialisation in c# handle both single digit and double digit hour

Tags: c#, json, datetime, json.net, datetime-format

I have a 3rd party application that send JSON DateTime in both single and double digit Hour format.  The hour is sent as single digit when less than 10 and double digit when greater than or equal to 10.

e.g.

2020-12-17T**9**:00:00.000-04:00

2020-12-17T**11**:00:00.000-04:00

I expect the 2020-12-17T9:00:00.000-04:00 sent as 2020-12-17T**09**:00:00.000-04:00.

Is there any DateFormatString that can handle both single and double digital hour?

Currently, I am using the default settings in Newtonsoft and it throws exception in parsing the single digit string to DateTime.

Comment: Are you able to provide feedback to the third-party application and get it fixed there? It's clearly *trying* to provide an ISO-8601 string, but that standard requires two digits. It would be better for them to fix their formatting than for every consumer to have to work around it being broken.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am planning to do.  I post it here to see if I am missing something.  I believe they pass an invalid format, but I want to double check before I ask..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I should not ask the question at the beginning.  It obviously the 3rd party company does not pass the right format.

For those who want to get the date time string in this format "2020-12-17T11:00:00.000-04:00", the format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffzzz"

var dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffzzz");